# AS3 - Instantiating objects from external .swf in iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I'm looking to load external .swfs that have graphical assets in them which are all 'exported for actionscript', and instantiate those assets in a .swf packaged for iOS.

I'm using the adt command line packager to create the .ipa file. I'm including the .swf files while packaging. The .swf files seem to load correctly, and give me no errors, but when the `Loader` for each .swf's `bytesLoaded` equals `bytesTotal` the `content` property remains null.

The program works perfectly when I package the .ipa using the `-target ipa-test-interpreter` flag, but not when I use the `-target ipa-test`.

I'm assuming the problem is that iOS doesn't allow Flex developers to load external .swf files that contain actionscript, and the 'export for actionscript' in the external .swf files counts as actionscript for the purposes of Apple's security policies. I'm looking for confirmation as to whether or not this is the problem.

**When using adt to package .ipa files, does iOS block external .swf files that have library assets that have been 'exported for actionscript'?**

Similar discussion: 
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3728665

Thanks!

J

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not allowed to load external swf files on apple devices when you are creating a app.

the solution for you would be: put all your graphics and everything else into swc file and then compile the one ipa file.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. As far as I know it is possible to load external .swf files that don't have any actionscript. See this discussion: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/862373 I'm wondering whether or not having MovieClips 'exported for actionscript' counts as actionscript in this case. Good point about, the .swc solution. It is one that I'm looking at implementing.

Comment: you can load an external swf files, but there must be only animation. as i recall you can not put there even `stop ();`

Comment: Well, a bit late, but just today i came to same problem, and found out, that AS linkage (export for actionscript) also count as code. SO no code on frame, no linkage, just plain elements.

Answer (score 0):

This **IS** possible.

However there are some limitations.

- You cannot use AS3 in the swf's if they are not loaded from the app
  source.
- And you have to run all the code in the same ApplicationDomain, which
  can cause weird errors with duplicate class names and such.

This is a official article from Adobe about how to do it:
http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/

I highly recommend using swc's as suggested by others tho, since it simplifies the process in many cases.